# Question about connecting an external mobile to Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I just started programming Java. In the Android Studio app, when I connect my mobile phone and write Java code, when I select the build option, I don't see any changes in the phone screen. I don't know what to do now.I activated both the developer option button and the USB debugging button.Please help me

Comment: disconnect your mobile and click `Revoke USB debugging authorizations`  option in your mobile again connect it. It will ask for permission click allow

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio use the **[Connection Assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#assistant)** to troubleshoot your device connection. Also, check your USB cable and port on your PC.